Let ideas and beliefs emerge organically
What does "organically" mean in "let ideas and beliefs emerge organically"?
"Organic" basically means "of, relating to, or derived from living organisms: organic matter", but how can ideas and beliefs emerge from living organisms? Thank you !

Looks like you checked a dictionary, but look a little harder! voting to close. (Also: how can ideas and beliefs emerge from anything other than living organisms?)

The notion that ideas or beliefs could "develop organically" (spring up naturally without any sort of plan or encouragement) got traction in the 1960s. This particular usage is a relatively recent development as language goes. It is "cant".

If you look at complete dictionary entries, one of the meanings of "organically" is:

in a way that happens or develops naturally over time, without being forced or planned by anyone


One of the meanings of 'organic; is 'naturally, without being forced or planned'.

organic adjective (OF CHANGES)
happening or developing naturally
over time, without being forced or planned by anyone:
Our policies are organic. They change as situations change.
His television career was an organic development from the endless
sketches he used to enact with his best friend from school.

Organic (Cambridge Dictionary)
